# Can a vector contain stacks?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I know that you can have a vector as the storage container for a stack though I'm wondering if you can have the data types stored in a vector as stacks. So if I had a vector named vector1, could vector1.at(2) return a stack instead of a data type such as int or double? I'm hoping that when the vector doubles in size, it can create more stacks during the runtime of the program as I don't know how many stacks I require until runtime.

Comment: You mean like a `std::vector<std::stack<int>>`? Absolutely. Have you tried it?

Comment: How would I then push data members into the stacks? Would I use both vector and stack functions or just stack functions? Also, how would I be able to tell the vector how many stacks I would like to create?

Comment: `vector1.at(2).push(42);`, for instance. You can specify a vector size when you construct it, or resize it, or `push_back`. Whatever you need.

Comment: So I could treat it much like an array where I can specify a position, then call a function?

Comment: Yup, you certainly can.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: *"a stack instead of a data type"* -- but a stack **is** a data type. (Well, `std:stack` is a template, which becomes a type once you supply template arguments, as in `std::stack<int>`.) Why do you think a stack is not a type?

Comment: Hmm... maybe you meant *"a stack instead of a **primitive** data type"* instead of *"a stack instead of a data type"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `std::vector` was designed as a template so that it can store any data type. The template argument can be as simple or as complex as you want. If you want each element of the vector to be a `std::stack<int>` then make that your vector's template argument.

```
std::vector< std::stack<int> > vector1;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------The vector's template argument
```

Compound containers can get confusing, so keep in mind which container is in play. The outer container is a vector. Elements (stacks) can be added with `insert`, `emplace`, `push_back`, etc.

```
vector1.emplace_back();  // Add an empty stack to the vector
```

The inner container (the template argument) is the return type of [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). An expression like `vector1.at(2)` evaluates to a stack (assuming that `vector1.size()` is at least 3). That stack can be manipulated as usual, using `vector1.at(2)` as its name.

```
vector1.at(2).push(7);  // Push 7 onto the third stack in the vector
vector1[2].pop();       // Remove the top element of the third stack in the vector
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes, and the answer for your question in comment is:

```
stack_name.push(element);
```

Also, look at this example:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  stack< int, vector<int> > stckk; 
  stckk.push(2);
  stckk.push(21);
  stckk.push(45);
  stckk.push(76);
  cout <<"Top Element is "<<stckk.top() << endl;
  
  while(!stckk.empty())
   { stckk.pop();
     if(stckk.empty())
     cout << "The Stack is now Empty." << endl;
   } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the function call for a normal stack? How would the program and compiler know which stack in the vector to push the element into if there are multiple stacks? The second example seems to be a stack using a vector container which is not what I'm hoping to do. I'm hoping to have a vector array filled with stacks.

Comment: The stacks in your vector *are* normal stacks. Just replace `stack_name` with `vector1.at(2)`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!